# PHP regexp: caseless modifier for part of the expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm wondering if it's possible in PHP to set regexp modifier for just a part of the expression (not whole expression).

I have the following code:

```
    $romanDigitsRegexp="(M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))";

    $test = "Properties of Wide Bandgap li-vi Semiconductors VolUme1";

    $volumeInfoFound = preg_match("/(\bv|Volume|\bvol)[\.| ]*(\d+|".$romanDigitsRegexp.")\b/i",$test, $matches);
```

This global /i modifier causes problem with roman digits. I would like to remove it but at the same time catch such words like "volume","VOLUME","vol","VOL", "Vol". Is it possible to add \i modifier just for this part:

```
(\bv|Volume|\bvol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch on/off modifiers like this:

```
(?i)subpattern(?-i)
```

note: the action of an inline modifier is limited to the innermost group. So `((?i)toto)abcd` doesn't match `totoABCD`. And a group doesn't protect against a modifier of an upper level: `(?i)(toto)abcd` matches `TOTOabcd`.

if you want to switch on a modifier for a subpattern enclosed in a non-capturing group you can use this syntax too:

```
(?i:subpattern)
```

The same to switch off:

```
(?-i:subpattern)
```

Note: unfortunately you can't do the same with an atomic group. *(You can't write `(?i>subpattern)`)*

For the two syntaxes you can switch several modifiers at the same time:

```
(?ix-m)

(?ix-ms:subpattern)
```

Note: it isn't forbidden to write `(?i-i)`, but it's useless.